# APNS notification sound for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I am having some trouble setting the message sound for my app.

So in the apns response sent by the server, I specify `"sound" : "default"`, and its all good. 
But if I set the `"sound":"chime"`, or `"sound":"note"`, they dont seem to work. It always plays Default.  Those are sounds i see form iPhone -> settings -> Sounds.

How can i use the "Note" as my preferred notification sound, or should i create my own sound, and add it to the bundle?

Comment: I am quite sure that you need to create you own sound and add it to the bundle.

Comment: As was mentioned in both current answers, if you want a different sound you need to include the file in your app. My guess is that apple doesn't want apps to play sounds that people might have configured for text messages, email, etc.

Comment: yeah. the fact that we cant choose the system sounds is not clear in the documentation. This gets even more confusing when apps like Whatsapp use the same tone as iMessage. And now, I realize they copied the sound, and added it to their bundle

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to play a sound other than the default one, you will need to package the sound in your bundle and specify the file name of the sound in the payload.  For example, if I were to include a sound file called `notificationCupcake.caf` in my app, I would include this JSON key/value pair in the push:

```
 "sound": "notificationCupcake.caf"
```

Comment: you mean ONLY default can be played without adding to app bundle? and all others sounds, even system sounds such as those mentioned [here](http://cocoathings.blogspot.com/2013/01/playing-system-sounds.html) or [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices) or [here](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary) can't be played unless added to app bundle?