# How to add a sound on a notification using Azure sdk

Tags: java, azure, audio, azure-notificationhub

Does anyone know how to add a sound with the notification hub of Azure on java.

What I've done is:

Added the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.windowsazure</groupId>
    <artifactId>NotificationHubs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And send a notification as the documentation explains:

```
            INotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub("connectionString", "hubPath"); 
            Notification n = Notification.createGcmNotification(message);
            Set<String> tags = new HashSet<>();
            tags.add(tag);
            hub.sendNotification(n, tags);
```

I was looking on how to add a sound but I could find it.

I'm planing to send notification to iOS and Android clients.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to add a sound with the notification hub of Azure on java.

Unfortuntly ,it is not supported on the Azure notification hub currently. I also find a similar [MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/301f016b-0c03-460c-becc-66f726ac734b/no-sound-in-push-notifications?forum=notificationhubs).

You could give your feedback to [azure team](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/218849-notification-hubs).

If you still want to do that. My workaround is that you could refer to [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) or [GCM](https://distriqt.github.io/ANE-PushNotifications/m.FCM-GCM%20Payload). Please also note the playload limited size.

Referece:

[Change push notification sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536591/change-push-notification-sound)