# How to play alarm tone in xamarin ios when local notification fires at specific time

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an app in xamarin ios in which I want to play alarm tone when notification fires and stop when user dismiss the notification. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please have a look in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536591/change-push-notification-sound

Comment: He wants to set sound on local notification not push notification .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [UNNotificationSound](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound?language=objc) , it is used to customize sound played upon delivery of a notification.

For local notifications, assign the sound object to the sound property of your UNMutableNotificationContent object.

##### Sample code

```
var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
content.Title = "Title";
content.Sound =  UNNotificationSound.GetCriticalSound("a.aiff");

var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(5, false);
var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier("a", content,trigger);
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, null);
```

##### Notice

1. Place the sound file in the following locations :

   - The /Library/Sounds directory of the app’s container directory.
   - The /Library/Sounds directory of one of the app’s shared group container
     directories.
   - The main bundle of the current executable.
2. The sound must be in one of the following audio data formats:

   - Linear PCM
   - MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
   - µLaw
   - aLaw

   You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file.
3. Sound files must be less than `30` seconds in length.
   If the sound file is longer than 30 seconds, the system plays the default sound instead.