# in iOS Remote Notification Custom Sound is not working

Tags: objective-c, iphone

> Blockquote

default sound is playing.i also use 
"wav", "caf" and "aiff" format and sound length is 5 second

Comment: Few things to check. 1. Have u added sound file to project 2. Is it correct format ? 3. Did u specify sound file name is push json ? Or follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478395/apns-notification-sound-for-ios

Comment: yes i added sound in project and it is in all of 3 format(caf,wav,aiff).

Comment: also specify sound in push json

Comment: Can u setup sample project on github n share link n will check